# Gauss law in surfaces

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

Suppose their is a uniformly charged infinitely long rod.
We consider a surface of fixed area at a certain distance from the rod. Is the flux and electric field due to rod uniform through out the surface of given area?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: There is a charged rod ,a plate . Is flux through plate uniform

Comment: Is plate charged or uncharged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to think how are the electric field lines set up in the surrounding area of the conductor.

Since, in your question the conductor is an infinite rod with shape of a cylinder, the equipotential surfaces will also be cylindrical. Fringing effect is not considered as the rod is infinite.

[image]

(Top view)

Uniform electric field is characterized by two conditions :

1. Equal magnitude
2. Equal spacing between electric field lines.

So it actually depends on how your plate is. If it superimposes an equipotential surface, then the electric field will be uniform for it, Otherwise not.

To find the E. field at an equipotential surface, you can use the gauss's law.